# Hibernate one-to-one, No row with the given identifier exists exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, one-to-one

I need a link between two entities, so I use a one-to-one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @OneToOne(optional = true)    
    @JoinColumn(name="login", referencedColumnName="person_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Person person;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private String personId;

    @Column(name = "pin")
    private String pin;
}
```

If there is no item for a particulary PERSON in table T_USER, user.getPerson throw a exception:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [packagename.com.entity.Person#scabriou]
```

But If I have reference between the 2 tables in the db, the getter works!

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: I don't want to have a exception when I call user.getPerson if there is no reference in table person for the user. I need to check if user.getPerson is not null I want to user.getPerson().getPin().

Comment: its a one-to-one not on a primary key.

Comment: It's not a one-to-one on primary key. You have a foreign key (login) in the T_USER table which references the person ID. Do you have values in this column that are not existing person IDs?

Comment: try adding the parameter "fetch=FetchType.LAZY" to your @OneToOne annotationo of Person in User

Comment: The annotation worked like a charm: @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) I used this for a log's table, where haven't forced integrity reference.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can't say if this the best solution but you could use the `@NotFound` annotation. E.g.

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Person person;
```

I believe person will remain `null` and the exception will not be thrown.

Comment: wouaw, thanks, I never saw thoses annotations. It works! Now, its the best solution...? Normaly, I know is better to use one-to-one on primary key but in this case I will use another way with @NotFound annotation.